# how to get datagrid control in wpf visual studio 2010

Tags: wpf, datagrid

how do we get the datagrid control in wpf visual studio 2010....I mean how to add the datagrid control to the wpf default controls..if I directly type  tag in my xaml code, it's giving an error to check the reference assembly that needs to be added..
could anyone please help me out to resolve it...

Comment: sorry, I do not know the version of WPF..but then it's on visual studio 2010 sp1 version where am unable to find it...

Comment: Right-click project, select Properties. Make sure it's .NET version 4.

Comment: thank you ..I found Target Framwork as .NetFramework 3.5...So,Now can I change it to version 4..

Comment: Thanks a lot.., I got that with framework 4...

Answer (score 0):

You can find it at the Common WPF Controls section in your Toolbox as you can see below. Just drag-and-drop it into your window designer and everything will be okay:

[image: DataGrid at the toolbox]

---

### Update

Then do the following steps:

1. Right click on your Toolbox and click on **Choose Items...**
   [image: Choose Items]
2. Filter the long list on the opened form by typing DataGrid as you can see on the image below:
   [image]

Comment: oh...thank you..i will have to try it for .net framework 3.5..because for 4.0 i could get it..anyways..thanks..