# New to C#, can't find data table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datatable

I am relatively new to C# and I want to try my hand at some very simple programs to just practice (not for homework, not for something I might do later, just want to get better). I found an example of a data table [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable) yet I can't find it in the **toolbox.**

Am I going about this the wrong way ? Is it possible to only add it trough code ? Or what ?

I know it does [exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Thank you, I now know it's not a visual representation and that what I was *actually* looking for data grid view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many MANY things that are not in the toolbox that you access directly through code.

(the rest of this answer assumes you are using Winforms not WPF)

The toolbox is mainly to make it easy to access things that have **a visual component to it**. If you are looking to ***display*** your DataTable the thing you are really looking for is a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)

[image]

You can add more things to the toolbox, just right click on the toolbox and go to `Choose Items...`

---

Also multiple DataTables can be contained in a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx). And if you look at my screenshot above, it is right below the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataTable` is a Class, but not a Control. ASP.NET controls are shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386451.aspx).

The toolbox only shows ASP.NET Controls. Yes, you need to add it through code instead of through the toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

A `DataTable`  is an object that contains rows of data - you can think of it as an in memory database table.  Normally you would create this object in code.  It is not in the Toolbox because it is not a visual component.

The visual component is the `DataGridView`.  That will be in the toolbox and you can drag and drop it onto your form.  That is what the tutorial you are looking at is using.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code in the example - pretty close to the top, there is:

```
using System.Data;
```

The `DataTable` class "lives" in this namespace.

You need to have that in your code as well.

`DataTable` is not a visual tool - it is a normal class and you will not be able to find it in the toolbox.

Items in the toolbox are there for visual components - things like forms, class diagrams and such.

Answer (score 1):

**DataTable** is not a UI component. The UI component, that you can drag onto a Window/Form is a **DataGrid**.

Both DataTable and DataGrid are not specific to C#, they are .NET classes and can be consumed via any .NET language (including C#, C++/CLI, F#, ...). **DataGrid is**, however, **specific to UI technology**, so you need to detail if you are using Winforms, WPF, Windows 8 UI, ASP.NET UI, Silverlight or etc.

What you can seen in the Toolbox, depends on the active document. If the active document is a UI designer, you can see UI components. If the active document is an Entity Framework designer, you can see Entity Framework Design elements and so on.

Here is an example of finding a DataGrid in the Toolbox (for WPF):
[how to get datagrid control in wpf visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330585/how-to-get-datagrid-control-in-wpf-visual-studio-2010)